# Sequentially cascading radiobutton forms with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working on creating a simple GUI for one of my codes, so that I can enter parameters without looking for the files or the lines they're defined. However, the definition is a sequential one. Up to now, I have this:

```
import tkinter as tk

def initiation():
   analysis_type = radiobutton_initial.get()
   label_dummy = tk.Label(gui, bg="#6D7BB4", fg='white',text="  ",font=('Courier', 14)).grid(row=2)
   if analysis_type==1:
       label2 = tk.Label(gui, bg="#6D7BB4", fg='white',
                         text="Please select the group you want to analyze:",
                         font=('Courier', 14))
       label2.grid(row=3, columnspan=2, sticky="w")

   if  analysis_type ==2:
       label2 = tk.Label(gui, bg="#6D7BB4", fg='white',
                         text="Please select the submethod you want to apply:",
                         font=('Courier', 14))
       label2.grid(row=3, columnspan=2, sticky="w")

   return analysis_type



gui = tk.Tk()

gui.geometry("800x500")
gui.title("Analysis Parameters")
gui.configure(bg='#6D7BB4')

label = tk.Label(gui,  bg="#6D7BB4", fg='white', text="Please select the analysis you want to conduct:", font=('Courier', 14))
label.grid(row=0, sticky="nw", columnspan=2)

# initial_text = tk.Text(gui, bg="#A0AEE1", height=3, font=("Arial", 16))
# initial_text.pack()

radiobutton_initial = tk.IntVar()
tk.Radiobutton(gui, text="Group Analysis\t\t", bg="#6D7BB4", fg='white', font=('Courier', 14), variable = radiobutton_initial, value=1, command=initiation).grid(row =1, column=0, sticky="w")
tk.Radiobutton(gui, text="Individual analysis", bg="#6D7BB4", fg='white', font=('Courier', 14), variable = radiobutton_initial, value = 2, command=initiation).grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="w")


gui.mainloop()
```

If one of the radiobuttons is selected, I want to ask other questions but the questions depend on the selected value. Then, given the new answer, another radiobutton set appears. It will be 5-6 sequential questions with some if-else conditions.

I also want to disable the option of changing previous answers.

I was not able to make `analysis_type` a global value, let alone cascading form. How should I go on?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?. I had to redo your code, because of duplicate. I had to remove `radiobutton` `fg='white'`.

```
import tkinter as tk

def initiation():
   analysis_type = radiobutton_initial.get()
   label_dummy = tk.Label(gui, bg="#6D7BB4", fg='white',text=analysis_type,font=('Courier', 14)).grid(row=2)
   if analysis_type == 1:
       label2.configure(text="Please select the group you want to analyze:")

   else:        
       label2.configure(text="Please select the submethod you want to apply:")

   return analysis_type



gui = tk.Tk()

gui.geometry("800x500")
gui.title("Analysis Parameters")
gui.configure(bg='#6D7BB4')

radiobutton_initial= radiobutton_initial = tk.IntVar()

label = tk.Label(gui,  bg="#6D7BB4", fg='white', text="Please select the analysis you want to conduct:", font=('Courier', 14))
label.grid(row=0, sticky="nw", columnspan=2)

 
label2 = tk.Label(gui, text='', bg="#6D7BB4", fg='white', font=('Courier', 14))
label2.grid(row=3, columnspan=2, sticky="w")

 

tk.Radiobutton(gui, text="Group Analysis\t\t", bg="#6D7BB4", font=('Courier', 8), variable=radiobutton_initial, value=1, command=initiation).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w")
tk.Radiobutton(gui, text="Individual analysis", bg="#6D7BB4", font=('Courier', 8), variable=radiobutton_initial, value=2, command=initiation).grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="w")


gui.mainloop()
```

Output image 1:

[image]

Output select `radiobutton` 1:

[image]

Output select `radiobutton` 2:

[image]

Comment: A part of it is, yes. After this label, how can I add a new set of radiobuttons that depend on the answer of previous questions? For example, if "Group Analysis" is selected, it will ask for the group to analyze. The answers can be, say, 1, 2, or 3. If 1 is selected, then another question with a new set of radiobuttons will come, and say, for example, "Do you want the means" with a yes or no question. But if Group 2 is selected, then the question will ask "Do you want an outlier analysis". It's a decision tree of questions.

Comment: You have to write for answer and Then we can help you.. I don't know know about your quiz games. You haven't mention in your question.